# Response.Write/Flush trava após muitas chamadas

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, stream

**DISCLAIMER:** Postei a mesma pergunta no StackOverflow em inglês, vou transportar a resposta válida de cá pra lá ou de lá pra cá caso seja necessário, mas sei que não são todos os usuários daqui que acessam o StackOverflow em inglês, então tive a intenção de ampliar o raio de resposta :)

### Problema

Estou tentando resolver este problema por dias.Temos um processo de importar registros de um arquivo **csv** para o **banco de dados**, através de uma página administrativa que reside em um projeto **ASP.NET Web Forms (.NET 4.0)**.O processo era lento e fiquei responsável por torná-lo mais ágil. Comecei alterando a lógica interna, o que já deu um ganho significativo no desempenho.

Porém, se eu fizer upload de arquivos grandes (bem, **relativamente grandes**, de no máximo 3MB), eu tenho que esperar até que o processo de upload termine até que eu comece a importar, e eu não retorno nenhuma informação de progresso para o cliente enquanto eu faço isso. O processo em si não é tão demorado, leva de 5 a 10 segundos para completar, e sim, eu já pensei em criar uma `Task` separada e utilizar *polling* para pingar o server, mas achei isso um canhão pra matar mosquito.

---

### O que fiz até agora?

Então, para corrigir este problema, decidi ler o *stream* do request e importar os valores enquanto o faço. Criei um *handler* genérico (.ashx), e coloquei o código a seguir dentro do método `void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)`:

```
using (var stream = context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream())
{
}
```

Primeiro eu removo os *headers* (cabeçalhos do request), e então eu leio o *stream* (através de um `StreamReader`) até que eu encontre um CRLF (\r\n), converto a linha para o meu *model*, e continuo lendo o CSV. Quando eu obtenho 200 arquivos (ou até o fim do arquivo), eu atualizo todos de uma vez na base de dados. Então, continuo o processo obtendo mais registros até o fim do arquivo.

Isso parece funcionar, mas daí eu decidi responder via *stream* também. Primeiramente, eu desabilitei o **BufferOutput**:

```
context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

E então, adicionei estes headers à minha resposta (*response*)

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Keep-Alive", "true");
context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
context.Response.ContentType = "application/X-MyUpdate";
```

Daí, após enviar os 200 registros para a base, eu escrevo no *response*:

```
response.Write(s);
response.Flush();
```

`s` é uma string de tamanho fixo de 256 chars. Eu sei que 256 chars nem sempre são iguais a 256 bytes, mas eu só queria ter a certeza de não escrever muralhas de texto de uma vez e estragar alguma coisa.

Eis o formato:

```
| pipeline (delimitador)
1 or 0 sucesso ou falha
; delimitador
mensagem de erro (se houver)
| pipeline (próximo delimitador)
```

Exemplo:

```
|0;"Preço inválido na linha 123"|1;|1;|0;"Id inválido na linha 127"|
```

No *client-side*, eu tenho isso aqui (apenas o trecho que faz o request):

```
function import(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = $('[data-id=file]')[0].files[0];
    formData.append('file', file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/Site/Update.ashx";

    xhr.onprogress = updateProgress;

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
    xhr.send(formData);
}

function updateProgress(evt){
    debugger;
}
```

---

### O que aconteceu :(

- Os dados não são enviados imediatamente para o *client* quando eu chamo `response.Flush`. Eu entendo que existe *buffering* do lado do cliente, mas mesmo assim parece não funcionar, mesmo quando eu envio um monte de lixo junto para passar por cima desse buffer.
- Depois de certo tempo, depois de escrever muita coisa no `Response.Write`, o método ficará progressivamente lento até travar. A mesma coisa pode ocorrer no `Response.Flush`. Acredito que eu esteja deixando alguma coisa passar batida aqui...
- Eu criei um projeto simples de webform para testar o que estou tentando fazer. Ele possui um *handler* genérico que vai retornar um número por segundo durante 10 segundos. Ele realmente atualiza (nem sempre na taxa de 1 segundo por atualização) e eu consigo ver progresso.
- Quando eu escrevo poucas linhas no *response*, o progresso é exibido (o evento é chamado), mas SEMPRE depois do processo estar quase terminando. O problema é que ao obter erros, eu escrevo estes erros no response. Ou seja, a mensagem fica maior do que quando tudo retorna sucesso, porque elas contêm as mensagens de erro.

Estou presumindo que se eu escrevo `Response.Flush` não é uma garantia de 100% de que o que eu escrevi vá imediatamente para o *client*, certo? Ou o problema é o próprio *client*? Se for o *client*, por que o servidor trava quando eu chamo o `Response.Write` muitas vezes?

Ficarei contente de prover mais informações caso julguem necessário.

Answer (score 3):

Conrad,

Acho que você já deve ter resolvido o problema mas vale a reflexão.

Achei sua solução bem inteligente e não entendo por que o flush está dando problema. Não acho que um arquivo de 3MB seja grande mas vejo que é preciso re-avaliar o propósito da funcionalidade. A solução que está usando agora é genuinamente complexa: você está estabelecendo uma conexão com o servidor, transmitindo o arquivo, inserindo no banco de dados e dando resposta do progresso tudo numa mesma operação, ao mesmo tempo. É muita coisa de uma vez só. Os riscos de erros e situações obscuridade são notáveis.

Soluções de pooling são interessantes, pelo menos as que tem base na criação de sessões temporárias no servidor para o cliente fique perguntando o status do processamento. Na imagem abaixo está a minha visão sobre uma arquitetura padrão de pooling para processos assíncronos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale refletir que se estivermos falando de um app de utilidade pública, com vários usuários, será melhor usar algo bem responsivo e cuidado. Soluções que causam boa impressão para o usuário são caras para o desenvolver e não tem jeito.

Mas se você considera isso "um canhão pra matar mosquito", então eu te encorajo a usar uma solução ainda mais simples. Por exemplo: Um processo onde seu servidor recebe o arquivo e processa as informações de forma assíncrona com direito de resposta detalhada no final. Este log poderia ser enviado por e-mail ou aparecer em alguma área específica.